# Create an input that allows only numbers, decimals and commas

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need the ability for my input to accept only numbers, decimals and commas. Using the `type=number` right now means I'm restricted to numbers and decimals, but I'm not sure how I can allow commas as well. Can anyone advise what I can do?

**JS**

```
var StopPrice = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
        stopPrice: 92.99
    }
  },

  updateStopPrice(stopPrice) {
    this.setState({
        stopPrice
    })
  },

  onChange(event) {    
    var stopPrice = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
        stopPrice
    });
  },

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input type="number" value={this.state.stopPrice} onChange={this.onChange} />
    </div>
  }
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/mjq9omyx/

Comment: Why do you need `'`?

Comment: Where exactly you want to allow the `'` to be entred? add an example of allowed format.

Comment: What is the question here? We are not clear.

Comment: Aplogies, I added the wrong character - it should be allowed to insert a period or a comma

Comment: FWIW Your example DOES allow me to type a `,` since it's the decimal separator in my browser's locale.

Comment: Thanks @pawel yeah thats cool, I just need to make both available no matter what

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html):

> value = floating-point number
>   A string representing a number.

And, if you go further, to the [spec for floating point](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float-def), you'll note you can't have any other characters.

To achieve the desired behaviour you can use the `pattern` attribute and specify a regex, e.g.

```
<input pattern="\d+((\.|,)\d+)?" />
```

The regex:

```
\d+((\.|,)\d+)?
```

Allows digits (\d), then an optional part:
either a dot or a comma (.|,) and more digits \d+.